# Is it possible to use Jenkins Webhooks with Github when the github account uses 2 factor auth

Tags: docker, jenkins, github, webhooks, two-factor-authentication

I am using the latest docker image for jenkins (jenkins/jenkins:lts JENKINS_VERSION 2.208). I have started the container, configured jenkins and can manually build against a public repo. However, on my github account I have 2FA, which must remain. I have created a personal access token in Github, and used this in my jenkins config for github server section. I have validated that the connection is working by pressing the test connection link (I added secret text that used my personal access token from github):[image: Jenkins Github server settings]

In Github, I have wekhook settings with the IP address for where jenkins is hosted (the IP for the docker container) follwed by github-webhook (I have also tried using a dns mapped address for jenkins as well, e.g., http://jenkins-local/github-webhook), content type is application/json:[image: Github Webhook Settings].

I have github polling enabled in jenkins as well, however, it does not work on push requests to the repo. I see failure logs in Github within the webhooks section, this increases each time I make a push (the request keeps failing). I have searched wide across the internet and found documentation of suggestions on what to do, including this link here: [securing your webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/), but nothing is giving me the desired polling effect when a push is initiated and a build triggered. So my question is, is it possible to use 2FA and github webhooks? If it is possible, then what are the exact steps to do it?

Comment: which secret did you add in secrets, is it the one from jenkins or a custom one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was to download ngrok. The IP address that the I had previously tried and the dns mapped address were not publicly available. I tried using my public ip address as well, but that also didn't work. In the end, downloading ngrok gave me a publicly accessible ip address (the address will look like the following: http://1212344a.ngrok.io). If you also plan to use ngrok then ensure that when you start it from the command line/terminal that you also pass the same port for the application that is running locally, if one is required. Next, in github - settings - webhooks set the payload url to the url that ngrok provides in the terminal output, but also append /github-webhook/ on to the end of the address to complete the payload url (in my case this was http://1212344a.ngrok.io/github-webhook/ as the full payload url).

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2FA enabled, you cannot authenticate with a login/pass from your tools anymore. You need to create a token that you will use in place of your password.

The [official documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) should get you there in almost no time.

Comment: So I have added my personal access token in place of the username and password as credentials within Jenkins > Configuration - Github - Github Servers section as secret text. When I test that connection with the PAT then I get a rate limit response, so I believe thar the connection works. But this doesn't solve the webhook issue, which continues to fail.

Comment: Well that seems like a different problem: either you are not recognized and limited because your IP as issued too many requests as anonymous... or your account as issued too many requests.